# Custom authorization filters to check email confirmation and resources ownership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

I would like to have a custom authorization filter like `[Verified]` to check if the user has is email confirmed which is a property of my `User` class (`IsEmailConfirmed`).
I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1) about authorization in .NET Core but not sure what the correct approach should be.

Additionally I would like to have another filter to check if an authenticated user is the owner of the resource he's trying to update/delete. All of my entities have a `CreatedBy` property so I would have to check that against the logged in user.

What authorization types (roles, claims, policy, etc.) are the most adequate to each scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Claims is usually used when there is a third party providing the Claim values. In your case, this won't be applicable.

You can use both Roles and Policy, however, Roles is the easiest to implement for first scenario. You can create a Role something like VerifiedUser and assign it to a User, whenever the email is verified. If this is the only requirement, the Roles is the best approach.

For the second scenario, Policy is the best way to implement, as it would require a DB call to fetch the resource and identify whether the Resource is accessible by the User or not. Since anyways, you will be implementing a Policy, you can implement the Email Verification in the policy model itself, eliminating the Roles approach.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of the implementation based on my question?

Comment: Please check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1